# nullpointerexception error on new installation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

A fresh installation of eclipse has been created as a result of this error (I deleted all the files, however I'm guessing I missed a few)

This is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at testing.testsrc.testcase1(testsrc.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Getting it on a brand new project too so believe this is away from any project specific configuration.

Can anyone assist?

EDIT:
As an example this code will also return the same error:

```
package testing;
package TestsStudies;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.awt.Desktop.Action;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Iterator;

public class TestingStd {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebElement sidearrow;
    WebElement sidemenu;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException { //Creating driver and connecting to url
        String baseURL = "url";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/user/Desktop/gecko/geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseURL);
        driver.findElement(By.id("isid")).sendKeys("username");
        WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        Password.sendKeys("password");
        Password.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);     
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@ src='/url/images/icons/logo_gif/Br.svg']")).click();;
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nosaveq\"]/div[3]/div[1]/span/img")).click();;
        Thread.sleep(1500);

    }

    @Test
    public void expDescriptionandSave() throws InterruptedException {

        sidemenu = driver.findElement(By.id("optionstd"));
        sidearrow = driver.findElement(By.id("slideButton_internal"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(sidemenu).perform();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        builder.moveToElement(sidearrow).click().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"unusedFolderProtocols\"]/div[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"unusedFolderProtocolsContent\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/img")).click(); //click BioELN
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println(timeStamp + " experimentDescriptionandSave");
        driver.switchTo().frame("details");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#experiments > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > textarea")).sendKeys(timeStamp);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='create study']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        String timeStampSecond = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println(timeStampSecond + " experimentDescriptionandSave");
        WebElement description = driver.findElement(By.name("DESCR"));
        description.clear();
        description.sendKeys(timeStampSecond);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"exp\"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/label[1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        String descriptionText = driver.findElement(By.name("DESCR")).getText();
        assertTrue(descriptionText.contains(timeStampSecond));


    }
```

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you installing, and which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: 1.8.0_131 Java and Eclipse is Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

Comment: which line is giving this exception?

Comment: I believe this to be independent of any specific project as I just reinstalled eclipse (as well as I could) and all test cases are failling with this error.

Comment: Did you create a new project to verify this independence?

Comment: @IRyg NPE doesn't arises from jar & exe. It arises from the code blocks. Consider showing your work please. Thanks

Comment: IMO, you didn't configure `ExplicitWait` properly somewhere & went ahead to use the instance of `ExplicitWait`. Hence the error. Thanks

Comment: I've added the code and unfortunately the error stays the same :(

Comment: where did you initialize the `driver`? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: you didn't initialize `driver`.  you defined it, but didn't initialize.

Comment: My apologies, it's an error I made while replicating it, turns out it is specific to that code, which i've now added, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you are not initializing your driver variable. The basic code would be -

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Also, based on what browser you want to use, you would need to download and then setup the corresponding driver as well. For Firefox, it's called GeckoDriver and for Chrome it's called ChromeDriver. Finally, you would need to provide the driver location in your script. So the code would look like this -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\some_folder\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

If you are looking for detailed steps, then you can follow this article - [Selenium WebDriver Setup](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3/)

Comment: Apologies, it seems that I've missed that when replicating, so strangely it seems that the issue is specific to that bit of code... I've added the code that's still producing the error, I'm fairly certain I've implemented it correctly as it was working before it decided to stop, I'm not sure what caused it. I also did create a new java project.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems that you haven't initialized your `driver`

So you might want to add two statements before you write `driver.get();` statement.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");  
   //Or any other browser's driver that you have used.
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Apologies, it seems that I've missed that when replicating, so strangely it seems that the issue is specific to that bit of code... I've added the code that's still producing the error, I'm fairly certain I've implemented it correctly as it was working before it decided to stop, I'm not sure what caused it. I did also create a new java project for this code